# PowerBi create an Editable Table

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-custom-visuals

I would like to create visual within PowerBi which is an editable table (cf. something similiar to what Acterys offers). So after editing the new rows should be written back to the database. The most common answer I found, was doing this by connecting an SQL database via DirectQuery and using a custom PowerApps visual. Yet, the SQL Connector for PowerApps seems to be restricted to premium capacities, so this is not an option.

So my question is: How else could I implement/script/code an editable table within PowerBi?

Comment: Power BI is reporting and data analysis tool, not an application builder. Change the tool you use to match the requirements you have (or change the requirements).

Comment: @Andrey Nikolov : I know PowerBi primarily adresses other issues, yet there are some use cases where editing some data would be very useful and a great addition to the tool. As I mentioned there are already some plugins that are able to edit data, so I am wondering how to create that myself...

Answer (score 0):

You can use PowerApps visual.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerapps/maker/canvas-apps/powerapps-custom-visual

In Power Apps, you can use the Vertical Gallery to display the records in a tabular form. I think there's also a editable form in PowerApps. I haven't explored it that much.

But, this would solve your requirement.

This is not an out of the box solution, so you will have to design every element of the solution, like table layout, filters, sorting, update/save button, etc.

I hope you find this helpful.

Best Regards,
Karthik

Answer (score 0):

You can either script your own visual for Power BI, or if you want to use PowerApps, you have to spend money.

Either way, a visual that will do that for you in Power BI is not out of the box and most likely an ISV vendor will charge you for this as well.

Either make users edit your data externally, build a visual that can handle it or buy a visual/license are the only options you have.